# Things to consider when creating a web framework

Tags: php, python, ruby, frameworks

I am not trying to create yet another web framework.

For one of the applications I am working on, I want to create a custom framework. I don't want to use any already available framework.

What are the common things to consider?

What should be the architecture?

Thanks :)

Comment: "I am not trying to create yet another web framework." and then "I want to create a custom framework" oO?

Comment: Yeah, I've got to say that making a framework for one application is totally not worth it - unless you feel that you will use this framework for future projects. Even then I would shy away from it unless I was 100% confident I could pull it off as well as the existing frameworks (efficiency, security, etc.).

Comment: If you seriously need to make a framework, you should already know the answer to all those questions. There are plenty of really good frameworks out there now that have taken thousands of man hours to build. You'll need a team of developers if you hope to come up with something better.

Answer (score 2):

If the point of a framework is to make tedious things easy, a good start would be to consider what is tedious.

Comment: This framework is not meant to be open sourced. I am using it for my own application. The reason I didnt choose any already available framework is, they are designed to be generic but I have specific needs.

The reason for this question here is to know other's feedback and make sure I 'm not missing something.

Comment: @Ashit, I think you misunderstand what generic means. It usually means it works for a variety of specific needs. Most likely including yours.

Answer (score 1):

*What are the common things to consider?*
Purpose. Usually, when you start building a piece of software, you have a purpose in mind. What will it do that other programs can't?

If you can't answer that question, then take any existing open source framework, change its name and your job is done. Now you have your own framework.

Comment: I didn't ask this question to know if I should rename some framework and use it.

Do you ask such questions here?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are going to write a custom framework then I assume the framework needs to be tailored to your needs, otherwise you would use one that is already available.  So figure out what your needs are and go from there ;)

What are the most often repeated operations in your application?  Is there a division of labor that a framework could make more apparent?

Comment: Well,
It a database application (uses CouchDB).
Mostly deals with Webservices and Feed processing.

The reason for this question is to get other's feedback and make sure I'm not missing anything.

Comment: If you're afraid of missing things, you'll usually get better responses to your question if you include what you've already thought about. People on StackOverflow like to know that you've put in some effort already.